# Unique XPath for two pages

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have two different HTML pages that contain:

```
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Part 1</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li><b>Part 2</b>consectetur adipisci elit,
        <br> sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore
        <br> et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="test">
    <b>Part 1</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    <br> <b>Part 2</b>consectetur adipisci elit,
    <br> <b>Part 3</b>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

I need an unique XPath that works with either and that extracts

```
"consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

in the first case and

```
"sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

in the second.

Comment: Would downvoters care to explain how this question is unclear or unuseful?   This is well explained (and is self-contained), unlike many XPath against HTML questions.

Comment: @kjhughes My guess would be "because it shows no indication that the OP was actually trying to solve the problem himself."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan**:  Select elements beneath the test `div` that contain a text node child that starts with `"Part"`, then select all following text node siblings.

**This XPath 1.0 expression,**

```
/div[@class='test']//*[ starts-with(text(),'Part') 
                        and not(following::*[starts-with(text(),'Part')])
                      ]/following-sibling::text()
```

**for page 1, repaired to be well-formed,**

```
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Part 1</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li><b>Part 2</b>consectetur adipisci elit,
        <br/> sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore
        <br/> et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**will select multiple text nodes,**

```
consectetur adipisci elit,

 sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore

 et dolore magna aliqua.
```

**which would have to be trimmed/concatenated outside of XPath 1.0 to yield,**

```
consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

**and for page 2, also repaired to be well-formed,**

```
<div class="test">
    <b>Part 1</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    <br/> <b>Part 2</b>consectetur adipisci elit,
    <br/> <b>Part 3</b>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

**will select**

```
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

**as requested.**

Comment: Perfect answer! But, for example, if I want to extract the "description" ("info" class) in this ([link](http://foolrulez.org/slide/reader/series/seitokai_yakuindomo/)) page?  It's possible  to obtain it without knowing the b tag content?

Comment: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped, and create a new question as clear as this one with your new query.  Be sure to state in it how to find "description" if you can't count on it as a label.  Thanks.